# Noun with the definite article as a subject of a sentence

Tags: grammar, definite-articles

Please, help me to clarify this question.

Assuming that there are many books I owe to a person and some of them are here on my table, is it correct to say:

"*The books I owe you are on my table*"?

Will it show that those books just belong to ones I owe to the person, and somewhere else are other books I owe him?
Or will it strictly mean that these are the only books I owe?

The confusion is because "the" is often used for an exhaustive list.

And if to say: "*The book I owe you is on my table*" - the same question - can it just show that this is one of those books and there are other books I owe somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> The books I owe you are on my table.

I believe the sentence means

> **All** the books I owe you are on my table now.

If you want to say that these are not *all* the books, you can say

> **Some** of the books I owe you are on my table.
>   (And there's a couple that I haven't read yet in my backpack).

Note that it would look a bit strange if you said the same without **some**:

> _ Books I owe you are on my table.

---

Similarly, the sentence

> **The** book I owe you is on my table

Will mean that's the only book you owe. To change the sentence to "one of the books I owe you", you can rephrase it thus:

> On my table there's **a** book I owe you.
>   or:
>   There's **one** book I owe you on my table.
>   or:
>   **One** of the books I owe you is on my desk. (kudos to Henry74)

Comment: For the singular, I would also suggest "One of the books I owe you is on my desk."